# Resizable electron browserWindow not showing in tablet mode

Tags: node.js, electron, resize, desktop-application, tablet

I'm developing an electron(V.4.1.4) app but the problem is when the browserWindow is resizable (true) in tablet mode the browserWindow is not showing.

I need to know when the computer is in tablet mode or how to make the browser window behave in tablet mode like in desktop mode.

i tried:

```
-react-device-detect
-mobile-device-detect
-win.setAlwaysOnTop(true, "floating", 1)
-alwaysOnTop: true
-screen.getPrimaryDisplay() to see touchSupport value (unknown)
```

There's anyway?

Thanks in advance!